# Shortcode PHP file for two conditions passed when do shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I've created a shortcode for PHP file plugin template, now the template has two HTML design one with icons displayed and another shows only the Name.

**Is it possible to trigger a bool when do_shotecode for icons in functions.php and then in the template file I check for bool and say if do_shortcode has parameter icon set to true then echo content with icons?**

---

**Paths for files I'm working on**

- functions.php: child-theme/
- plugin template: child-theme/folderName/plugin_template.php

---

**Basic code e.g**

```
<?php if(do_shortcode_bool_with_icons == true ) { ?>
<h2>Print Items with Icons </h2>

<ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
</ul>
<?php } ?>


<?php if(do_shortcode_bool_text_only == true ) { ?>

<h2>Print Names only without icons</h2>

<ol>
    <li>Coffee</li>
</ol>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `do_shortcode()` function takes two parameters, `string $content, bool $ignore_html = false`. If you can grab the content string before it is passed to the function, then you could do `strpos()` or some kind of regex to check, which parameters are present in the shortocode string. But otherwise I don't think there's a way to do the kind of conditional check you're asking outside of `do_shortcode()`.

A much more simpler, and more explicit, way to do the same thing is to include the conditional check inside your shortcode callback. Then you can have a default value (e.g. true/false) for rendering the icons and match it with the parameters passed to your shortcode.

For example your shortcode is used like this,

> [your_shortcode icons="true"]

Your callback would then look like this,

```
add_shortcode( 'your_shortcode', 'your_shortcode_callback' )
function your_shortcode_callback( $atts ) {

  $default = array(
    'icons' => false,
  );
  $atts = shortcode_atts( $default, $atts, 'your_shortcode' );

  if ( $atts['icons'] ) {

    // return markup with icons

  } else {

    // return markup without icons

  }

}
```